# Inconsistent system

Tags: linear-algebra

I have got the following system:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&1\\-2&1&2\\-1&3&3\end{pmatrix} \qquad b=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Where $Ax = b$

And I have to retrieve $x$. 
Since it's an inconsistent system, I've tried least squares and pseudo-inverse to get an approximation, but nothing seems to work.
It's a question of a test and the asnwer "the system is inconsistent" is not accepted.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you not reduce it to SNF and show that there is no solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. There is no solution to the system you have given. That is easy to demonstrate.

Suppose there is a solution $(x,y,z)^T$, then you have

$x+2y+z=1$ (1)

$-2x+y+2z=1$ (2) and

$-x+3y+3z=-1$ (3)

Taking (1)+(3): $5y+4z=0$. Taking 2(3)-(2): $5y+4z=-3$.

Contradiction. So there are no solutions. You should check that you recorded the question correctly.